# Simple Java Textfile not parsing Correctly

Tags: java, parsing, text

I have a simple textfile:

```
type = "hello"
number = 66

type = "hey"
number = 77
```

I'm basically just checking to see if the string "type" is found in the textfile, if yes, I'd also like to get the values "hello" and "hey" i.e the types. However, my program doesn't work at all in that sense it all always prints no, when checking if "type" is in the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 1)
        parseText(argv[0]); // call with textfile name
}
public void parseText(String inPath) {
        try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(inPath);
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            if("type".equals(s.nextLine().trim()))
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else {
                System.out.println("no");
            }

        }
        }catch (Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("\nFILE NOT FOUND");
        }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to read from a file, you'll need to open one with `new Scanner(new File(inPath));` at a minimum. As it stands, you are just scanning the string passed in on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if("type".equals(s.nextLine().trim()))
```

You really want to read the line of data from the file into a String so you can do processing on the string.

You want to know if the line starts with "type":

```
String line = s.nextLine()

if (line.startsWith("type"))
{
    String value = line.substring(8);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Alright, but I'm still confused on how I would get the values "hello" or "hey"?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the line starts with "type" (not is equal to "type").

```
if("type".equals(s.nextLine().trim()))
```

should be something like

```
String line = s.nextLine().trim();
if (line.startsWith("type"))
```